# No Such Element Exception when using Scanner

Tags: java, file-io, io

I am attempting to read a txt file. I keep getting a "no such element" error and I cannot understand why. My code is,

```
File myFile = new File(input.txt)
Scanner reader = new Scanner(myFile);

for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
{
    name[i] = reader.nextLine();
    grade[i] = reader.nextInt();
    reader.nextLine();
    rank[i] = reader.nextInt();
    reader.nextLine();
}
reader.close();
```

Here is an [example of the file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWp6A.png).
What am I missing?

Comment: What's the definition of `name`, `grade`, and `rank`?

Comment: Maybe because you're trying to read 20 names, grades and ranks from a file that contains only three of each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why using a `for` loop is a bad idea when reading from a file; you don't know (rather, you shouldn't care for most intents and purposes) how large your file is.

Switch it out for a `while` loop:

```
while(reader.hasNext()) {
    // code
}
```

(Don't forget to advance `i` in the loop.)

Provided that your tokens are divided up into exact multiples of three, this will read the tokens in without running out of stuff to read from.

Comment: so the next problem is when i do that is i have a lot space for elements to be added later in the arrays so how do i a lot space but not have it print out the empty spots

Comment: Sounds like another question to me.  From the sounds of it, though, you want to loop over the elements in the array, and if it's not null, print something.

Comment: Maybe you should use an `ArrayList`, which grows itself automatically.

Comment: @DavidWallace:  This sounds like the opposite problem - too much space for elements, and you have to print out everything but the stuff that isn't there.

Comment: @David Wallace i unfortunately cant use an array list for this assignment its for school I would totally use it if i could :(

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not a good choice to use `for` loop.

You can try something like this:

```
int i=0;
int i1=0;
int i2=0;
int i3=0;

while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
    i++;
    if(i==1){
        name[i1]=reader.nextLine();
        i1++;
    }
    if(i==2){
        grade[i2]=Integer.valueOf(reader.nextLine());
        i2++;
    }
    if(i==3){
        rank[i3]=Integer.valueOf(reader.nextLine());
        i3++;
        i=0;
    }
}
```